# BeyondCompare comparison of XML files - Ignore specific elements during folder compare

Tags: xml, beyondcompare, beyondcompare3

I'm comparing folders containing XML files and wish to ignore specific nodes in the files when the directory compare is done...whether they have a value or not.

```
File 1
<myElement>value</myElement>
File 2
<myElement/>

File 1
<myElement>value1</myElement>
File 2
<myElement>value2</myElement>
```

I have BeyondCompare 3 and am using the xmlTidy sorted attributes plugin.

I have searched the BeyondCompare forums and Googled and can't seem to find step by step instructions that work.  I'm sure it isn't that hard but I'm just not getting it.  Can you clear the fog for me or give me a link?  Thanks.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Here's how to ignore text differences in files in the Folder Compare:

1. Load two folders in Beyond Compare's **Folder Compare**.
2. Double click to view a pair of XML files in the **Text Compare**.
3. Click the **Rules** toolbar button (referee icon).
4. Click **Edit Grammar**.
5. Click **New**.
6. Name it MyElement.
7. Select **Delimited** as the category.
8. Text from: `<myElement>` to: `</myElement>`.
9. Click OK.
10. Click OK.
11. Uncheck myElement to make it unimportant.
12. Change the dropdown at the bottom of the dialog from **Use for this view only** to **Use for all files within parent session** or **Update session defaults**.
13. Close the **Text Compare** tab.
14. In the **Folder Compare**, click the **Rules** toolbar button (referee icon).
15. Check **Compare Contents** and select **Rules-based comparison**.
16. Click OK.
17. Make sure **View > Ignore Unimportant Differences** is turned on.

The default settings in the Folder Compare use file size and modified date for comparison. Rules-based comparison uses the same content comparison method as double clicking to view file contents.

See also the article [Define Unimportant Text in Beyond Compare](http://www.scootersoftware.com/support.php?zz=kb_unimportantv3). It describes ignoring differences when viewing a pair of files in the Text Compare.

Comment: Thanks, that did it!  Mostly I was missing the Importance only showing when viewing two files.